# "Failed to write the version file to the artifact cache:" error

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am learning flutter and I want to run my first flutter app, however when I enter "flutter run" command I got the "Failed to write the version file to the artifact cache:" error

Below is the screenshot of the error

[image]

I am struggling with these error from last 2 days, please help me

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it is a permission issue, just make sure that you have ownership rights over the flutter installation folder!

You can check this [link](https://www.laptopmag.com/articles/take-ownership-folder-windows-10-using-file-explorer) for more information about changing files/folders ownership on Windows 10.

If this does not work, try to run PowerShell as admin and see if it's working, if it does then it definitely is a permission issue.

Comment: Yeah it solved the temporarily but when I again restarted my computer same error pop up.

Comment: Can you try to install Flutter in your working directory ? For instance C:/user/yournam/tools/flutter

Comment: I am talking about your user home directory

Comment: Sorry for late reply .. I install flutter in user home directory but it gave me these error        "Could not create service of type ScriptPluginFactory using BuildScopeServices.createScriptPluginFactory()."